# Separate multiple subdomains into all possible subdomain combinations using bash and awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, printf, subdomain

I'm trying to separate multiple subdomains into all possible subdomain combinations using bash.

For example if `subdomains.txt` has:

```
www.ir.example.com
www.it.api4.qa.example.com
www.api.example2.com
```

The expected output has to be:

```
example.com
ir.example.com
www.ir.example.com
qa.example.com
api4.qa.example.com
it.api4.qa.example.com
example2.com
api.example2.com
www.api.example2.com
```

I think that the best idea is to use the `.` to separate the subdomains without breaking the original domain but i'm not sure how to achieve this, any help it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Are you using a particular programming language?  Most languages, such as Java, C#, JavaScript, Ruby, etc. have packages which can extract the various components of a URL/URI.  These packages already exist, and you just need to call them.  I would look into this first before trying to reinvent the wheel with a complex regex.

Comment: I was thinking on using BASH. I'm trying to think on the correct syntax but i'm not sure how.

Comment: I just add more info.

Comment: There have been multiple near-duplicates recently. You all seem to be taking the same course and almost all of you seem to believe that Stack Overflow will want to solve your homework without any substantial effort from you.

Comment: Do you deal only with .COM domain names? If not, the problem is far more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}           # Set the input and output field separator to a dot
     {
        for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {      # Number of domains to print
          for(j=i;j<NF;j++)      # For each domain element
            d=d $j OFS;          # d is the domain
          a[d $NF]               # store it in the array a
          d=""                   # Reset the domain
        }
     }
     END{
       for(i in a)               # Loop through each element of the array a
         print i                 # and print it
     }' file
```

Note the use of the array `a` is for having unique domain name (and not twice `example.com`).

Note also the domain are not sorted, you may pipe the command through `sort` if needed.

Comment: Amazing, this works great and I did learn on the process. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Perl comes with any linux distro as far as I know (and some UNIXes). So I throw here an alternative with perl:

`perl -e 'while(<>){while(s/^([^.]+\.)(.+)/$2/){$x{$1.$2}=1}}print "$_\n" foreach(keys %x)' subdomains.txt`

The code, *'unfolded'*:

```
while(<>){ # read file line by line. Store line at $_
  # Match first subdomain to group $1 and the rest to group $2
  # replace by $2, so we will remove the first subdomain part
  while(s/^([^.]+\.)(.+)/$2/){ 
    # Store it on a hash (that will avoid printing duplicates)
    $x{$1.$2}=1
  }
}
# print the keys of the hash
print "$_\n" foreach(keys %x)
```

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about using linux and perl doesn't come as standard on all UNIX installations so YMMV. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html for the list of POSIX utilities.

Comment: @EdMorton Totally right. Still, I would say that perl is widespread enough to consider an alternative with it. I added the warning about UNIX systems. Thanks!

Comment: Right, I wouldn't have said anything if you hadn't said `Perl comes with any linux distro` as linux wasn't mentioned by the OP and some people seem to think that all UNIX is linux rather than linux being just one of the many variants of a UNIX system so I didn't want there to be any misunderstanding from people reading that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/\./#/g;:a;/#/!{p;bb};s/#([^#]+)$/.\1/;h;s/.*#//p;g;ta;:b' subdomains.txt
```

Comment: No need of label b here, :b is the end so b(jump to end is enough).You must tell this only work wirh gnu sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk

```
awk -F'.' '{b=$NF;for(i=NF-1;i>0;i--){b=$i FS b;print b}}' infile
```